# Mapstruct default value for LocalDate

Tags: java, mapstruct, localdate

How to use defaultValue for LocalDate using Mapstruct? I was trying everything and nothing works.
My failed attempts below:

```
@Mapping(target = "bornDate", defaultValue = "2019-10-11", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Person kidToPerson(Kid kid);

@Mapping(target = "bornDate", defaultExpression = "java(LocalDate.MIN)", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Person kidToPerson(Kid kid);

@Mapping(target = "bornDate", defaultExpression = "java(LocalDate.parse(2019-01-01))", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Person kidToPerson(Kid kid);
```

I just want to have some default value after mapping in my property `LocalDate bornDate` from Person.

Comment: could you post the source and target as well.

Comment: Why are those attempts failed? What kind of errors did you have?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
@Mapper(imports = {LocalDate.class})
public interface MyMapper {
    @Mapping(target = "bornDate", defaultExpression ="java(LocalDate.of(2019,12,31))")
    Person kidToPerson(Kid kid);
}
```